# CMake get HOSTNAME environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cmake, environment-variables

I have both HOSTNAME and USER defined as environment variables (Linux Ubuntu)

```
echo $USER
pvicente
echo $HOSTNAME
glace
```

I get the variables in CMakeLists.txt using

```
message("-- USER environment variable is set to: " $ENV{USER})
message("-- HOSTNAME environment variable is set to: " $ENV{HOSTNAME})
```

but USER is detected and not HOSTNAME

output is

```
-- USER environment variable is set to: pvicente
-- HOSTNAME environment variable is set to:
```

Comment: Where are defined HOSTNAME and USER variables ?

Comment: @MattSchuchard HOSTNAME is an environment variable...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could check which environment variables CMake does see with

```
$ cmake -E environment
```

It gives my hostname in an environment variable named `NAME`. So try:

```
message("-- USER environment variable is set to: " $ENV{USER})
message("-- HOSTNAME environment variable is set to: " $ENV{NAME})
```

But the official cross-platform CMake way is:

```
cmake_host_system_information(RESULT _host_name QUERY HOSTNAME)
message("-- _host_name variable is set to: " ${_host_name})
```

**Reference**

- [`cmake_host_system_information()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_host_system_information.html)

Comment: Why `_host_name` and not just `host_name`?

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone running into the same problem as I did: cmake_host_system_information only worked correctly for me when I placed it after the project(...) command.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I don't work with `cmake` so I did a bit of googling and came up with the following ... a bit more than I could fit into a comment ...

According to the first post @ this [link](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=cmake@cmake.org&q=subject:%22Re%3A+%5BCMake%5D+%24ENV%7BHOSTNAME%7D%22&o=newest&f=1):

- `sh -c echo \$HOSTNAME`   => ...nothing... ; `HOSTNAME` is **not**
  (automatically) set under the `sh` shell
- `bash -c echo \$HOSTNAME` => glace ; `HOSTNAME` **is** (automatically) set under the `bash` shell
- `cmake` runs commands under the `sh` shell, so `HOSTNAME` will not be available to `cmake`

At the bottom of that same link there's a recommendation to use the `site_name()` function ...

```
SITE_NAME(mySite)             => obtain hostname and place in variable 'mySite'
MESSAGE(mySite='${mySite}')
```

... which appears to jive with the (sparse) documentation ([site_name() documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/site_name.html))