How to turn ON or OFF object detection function Depending on HOSTNAME in CMake
I have a 2 robot. One has GPU, another doesn't have GPU so, I'm trying to make codes which cover all of cases. But it doesn't work.
My CMake is like below:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# ============================================
set(HOSTNAME_FILE_PATH "/proc/sys/kernel/hostname")

set(FILE_EXISTS OFF)
if(EXISTS ${HOSTNAME_FILE_PATH})
    set(FILE_EXISTS ON)
endif()
# ============================================
# ============================================
set(HOSTNAME "" STRING)
if(FILE_EXISTS)
    execute_process(
        COMMAND cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE HOSTNAME
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
endif()
# ============================================
# ============================================
set(ROBOT_DETECTION OFF)
if(HOSTNAME STREQUAL "robot1")
    set(ROBOT_DETECTION ON)
endif()
# ============================================

if(ROBOT_DETECTION)
    ~GPU code~
else()
    ~NO GPU code~
endif()


why not detect if it has the gpu? It looks doesn't work. What does it mean "doesn't work"? What happens? You can get hostname from cmake https://stackoverflow.com/a/46122556/9072753 .
